# WordPress 404 URL Control

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin. I created a shortcode on page

http://example.com/mypage

My shortcode is working fine.
I also want to get all urls

http://example.com/mypage/xxx

http://example.com/mypage/yyy

http://example.com/mypage/zzz

and want to execute my codes there. I am getting 404 error on http://example.com/mypage/xxx

Remember pretty permalinks are enabled and working fine.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Simple shortcode is added on http://example.com/mypage but i want to capture all subpages on it.

Comment: Nobody is able to answer my question.;